# Practice with functions - triangular number function isn't working in C

Tags: c

I have no idea what's wrong with this code. I'm getting errors in the 'process it' function.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{

    double getIt();
    {
        double num;
        printf("Please enter a number: ");
        scanf("%lf",&num);
        return num;
    }

    double processIt(double triangNum);
    {
        for (int counter=1;counter<=triangNum;counter++)
        {
            triangNum=triangNum+counter;
        }
        return triangNum;
    }

    void printIt(double orig,double triang);
    {
        double orig;
        double triang;

        printf("Your original number is %lf, while your triangular number is %lf",orig,triang);
    }

    int main();
    {
        double origNum=getIt();
        double triangNum=processIt(origNum);
        printIt(origNum,triangNum);
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are you dealing with `double` here?

Comment: Next time you get errors, **list them in your post**. (However, looking at the reactions, I can see why you shied away from that.)

Answer (score 3):

Remove semicolon after every starting statement of function definition !
  for ex.

```
double getIt() // no semicolon here
{
 double num;
 printf("Please enter a number: ");
 scanf("%lf",&num);
 return num;
}
```

Comment: While using xcode, I get an error and it tells me to put a semicolon at the end of the function.

Comment: Who tells you to put a semicolon ?

Comment: @user2276450 Have you even bothered to have a look at my answer? (And a C book? Or whatever?) You can't put one function inside another.

Comment: @user2276450 A proper C book is all you need !

Comment: Sorry, just saw it. I removed the first int main and it takes in the number, but the printIt function doesn't work.

Comment: @user2276450 Of course it doesn't work, because you're printing the two uninitialized local variables instead of the function arguments (which are shadowed). Apparently you have absolutely no idea at all what you are doing. Learn C properly to a basic extent, invest some effort in it, so that you at least know the fundamentals of the syntax. ***Pretty please don't waste our time.***

Comment: There are many errors in your question ! You have used for loop initial declaration which only allowed in C99 !

Comment: @KaustavRay Silence is golden. It's perfectly valid in C99.

Comment: By mistake I wrote that thing ! it is only allowed in C99 !

Comment: @KaustavRay Okay. And where's the mistake in that? I use C99 all the time (and probably should everyone who doesn't care about Microsoft being dumb and not supporting it). It's not an error or a mistake to use C99 features.

Answer (score 2):

Not to mention that you have two `main()` functions; one embedded into the other... you can't do that in C. You'll need to move **all** function definitions to the global scope (and before all, read a beginner C tutorial).

Answer (score 2):

After removing semicolons, also note that in `double processIt(double triangNum)`

```
 for (int counter=1;counter<=triangNum;counter++)
{
    triangNum=triangNum+counter;
}
```

you keep increasing `triangNum` by `counter` in each iteration and `counter` always remains less than `triangNum`, so the `for` loop never ends.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever was wrong with your loop before, was resulting in `triangNum` being a garbage number. Getting the `nth` triangle number is a simple equation:

```
double processIt(double n)
{
    return (n * (n+1))/2;
}
```

For example for an input of `5`, this returns `15`.

---

Other things wrong with your code:

Your local declarations of `orig` and `triang` are overshadowing your parameters.

```
void printIt(double orig,double triang);
{
    // double orig;
    // double triang;

    printf("Your original number is %lf, while your triangular number is %lf",orig,triang);
}
```

And issues pointed out in other answers: You're embedding your entire program inside main and putting semi-colons after function declarations.